# SymbolSource allowing the packages to be overwritten

Tags: nuget, symbols

In NuGet we get "allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush" to set to "false" in web.config if we want to prevent the pushing of a package which already exists.

I want to do the same for the SymbolSource instance which I am running locally on my machine. Is there any place where I can configure the same?

Right now it is happily allowing the overwriting of the packages.